# Program crashes when trying to open one screen

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I'm working on a project for an android class.  On this particular screen, when it tries to load, it crashes.  I cleaned up one null pointer exception, but now I'm getting a new error and can't figure it out. I haven't finished coding the activity, just reading the xml file at this point and trying to have one of the tags populate a spinner.... Here's the code for that activity:

```
public class PlayGeoTreasureActivity extends Activity {

    String[] treasureList=null;
    String[] clue1List=null;
    String[] clue2List=null;
    String[] clue3List=null;
    String[] answerList=null;
    String[] locationList=null;
    String[] pointValueList=null;

    XmlPullParserFactory parser;
    XmlPullParser xpp;

    Spinner spinnerTreasures;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_geo_treasure);

        spinnerTreasures = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.treasuresSpinner);

        //get the xml file
        File filename = new File(getFilesDir(), "treasure.xml");

        //check to see if file exists.  If it does, read it.

        try {
        if(filename.exists())
        {       
            readXML(filename);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(null, "File not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }  
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            String errorMessage=(e.getMessage()==null)?"Message is Empty":e.getMessage();
            Log.e("GeoTreasureGameLog",errorMessage);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            String errMessage=(e.getMessage()==null)?"Message is Empty":e.getMessage();
            Log.e("GeoTreasureGameLog",errMessage);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    private void readXML(File filename) throws XmlPullParserException, FileNotFoundException {
        // pull parser to read xml file
                    parser = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                    xpp = parser.newPullParser();

                    // point the xml parser to file
                    xpp.setInput(new FileReader(filename)); 

                    // get start and end tags
                    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

                    // set current tag
                    String currentTag;

                    // current value of the tag's element
                    String currentElement;

                    //int counter = 0;
                    try{
                    // parse the entire xml file until done
                    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
                    { 
                        // look for start tags
                        if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                        {
                            // get the name of the start tag
                            currentTag = xpp.getName();

                            if (currentTag.equals("TreasureName"))
                            {
                                currentElement = xpp.nextText();
                                treasureList.equals(currentElement);
                            }
                                else if (currentTag.equals("ClueOne"))
                                {
                                    currentElement = xpp.nextText();
                                    clue1List.equals(currentElement);
                                }
                                else if (currentTag.equals("ClueTwo"))
                                {
                                    currentElement = xpp.nextText();
                                    clue2List.equals(currentElement);
                                }
                                else if (currentTag.equals("ClueThree"))
                                {
                                    currentElement = xpp.nextText();
                                    clue3List.equals(currentElement);
                                }
                                else if (currentTag.equals("Answer"))
                                {
                                    currentElement = xpp.nextText();
                                    answerList.equals(currentElement);
                                }
                                else if (currentTag.equals("TreasureLocation"))
                                {
                                    currentElement = xpp.nextText();
                                    locationList.equals(currentElement);
                                }
                                else if (currentTag.equals("PointValue"))
                                {
                                    currentElement = xpp.nextText();
                                    pointValueList.equals(currentElement);
                                }
                        }
                        eventType = xpp.next();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e)

                    {
                        Log.e("GeoTreasureGameLog", e.getMessage());

                    }
                    Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,treasureList);
                    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.play_geo_treasure, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

And the error message: (new pointer Exception)

```
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rasmussen.geotreasuresgame/com.rasmussen.geotreasuresgame.PlayGeoTreasureActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at com.rasmussen.geotreasuresgame.PlayGeoTreasureActivity.readXML(PlayGeoTreasureActivity.java:137)
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at com.rasmussen.geotreasuresgame.PlayGeoTreasureActivity.onCreate(PlayGeoTreasureActivity.java:49)
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-17 09:13:24.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     ... 11 more
```

Here's the xml for the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".PlayGeoTreasureActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/treasuresSpinner"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/treasuresSpinner"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cameraShot"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/treasuresSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/guessLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/treasuresSpinner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/getClueBtn"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="@string/guessLblTxt"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/guessEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/guessLabel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/getClueBtn"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/foundBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/guessEditText"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/getClueBtn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/guessEditText"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="@string/foundBtnTxt" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pointsLbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/guessLabel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/foundBtn"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="@string/pointsEarnedLblTxt"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pointEarnedEditTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/pointsLbl"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pointsLbl"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/foundBtn"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/getClueBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/treasuresSpinner"
        android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/guessLabel"
        android:text="@string/getClueBtnTxt" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've been struggling with this for 3 days now.  All the other screens are working fine.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!!

Comment: The problem seams to be in the readXML method. You have en exeption there. Look in the error log you have a NPE again.

Comment: what is the code in this line 137 `PlayGeoTreasureActivity.readXML(PlayGeoTreasureActivity.java`? i think it is the `Log.e();`, i would prefer use `e.printStackTrace();` instead of `Log.e(...);`

Comment: by the way: you shouldn't use String errorMessage=(e.getMessage()==null)?"Message is Empty":e.getMessage();
Use TextUtils.isEmpty(e.getMessage()) instead

Comment: Use Log.e at the request of my professor.  I'll check readXML method again. Thanks!

Comment: so if you insist for the Log.e() method , use it like this : `Log.e("TAG", (e.getMessage() == null || e.getMessage().trim().equals("")) ? "Exception Message is empty": e.getMessage());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Oracle Throwable documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#toString%28%29)
it is said that .getMessage can return null.

So I would suggest that you change
`e.getMessage()` into `e.toString()`.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this, but still getting the same error message.

Comment: Correction, fixed one problem...now getting nullPointerException on the ArrayList.  Thanks for your help with the first error!!

Answer (score 2):

```
Log.e("GeoTreasureGameLog", e.getMessage());
```

`getMessage` apparently returns null. You should check for that.

Or better, just get rid of the try/catch during debugging. You will get a full stack trace in that case (instead of one that originates inside the catch statement).

Edit: you'll need to bubble these up by adding Throws statements to the method signatures, but you might get stuck there at some point. Instead you could replace the `Log.e(...);` by a `e.printStackTrace();`. Hopefully that gives you more details about what is going wrong.

Comment: If I remove the try/catch, I get a syntax error for unhandled exceptions.